# Getting BGP peers of an ExpressRoute gateway

Tags: azure, gateway, azure-virtual-network, azure-hybrid-connections

I am trying to pull the IP addresses of BGP speakers that establish a peering with an ExpressRoute gateway. For instance, if I create a VirtualNetworkGatewayConnection between my ExpressRoute circuit and an ER gateway, how do I get the IP addresses of the BGP endpoints on the circuit that peer with my gateway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could take a look at [ExpressRoute REST API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/expressroute/) and [Virtual Network Gateways API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/network-gateway/virtualnetworkgateways)

For example, you could get all peerings information in a specified express route circuit [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/expressroute/expressroutecircuitpeerings/list) via clicking the Green `Try it` on that page. Or try to retrieve a list of routes the virtual network gateway has learned, including routes learned from BGP peers [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/network-gateway/virtualnetworkgateways/getlearnedroutes). It might display the IP address of BGP endpoints in the routing table.

Comment: The peering information, however, only gives peer IP addresses towards the customer. I don't think the gateway establishes BGP with them.
Getting the routes from the gateway and inferring the peer IPs on the circuit is helpful if I have only one circuit. However, if I have 2 circuits peered with the Expressroute gateway, how do I know which peer in the gateway's routing table maps to each circuit?

Comment: It seems that you can refer to `origin` or `sourcePeer` in the [GatewayRoute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/network-gateway/virtualnetworkgateways/getlearnedroutes#gatewayroute) details.

Comment: Using sourcePeer looks promising! If I have 2 or more circuits peering with my gateway, how I do find the circuit that a given sourcePeer belongs to?

Comment: Read [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-circuit-peerings)`An ExpressRoute circuit has multiple routing domains/peerings associated with it: Azure public, Azure private, and Microsoft. Each peering is configured identically on a pair of routers `. Also, there are self-setup [IP addresses used for peerings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/expressroute/expressroute-routing#ip-addresses-used-for-peerings). You should know each peering IP range before you configure the peerings..

Comment: The addresses for the peerings are between my network and MSEEs. Isn't there a separate BGP peering between the Gateway and MSEEs with a different set of IPs? I was looking for the latter for a circuit. So, if I get the GatewayRoute details, is the sourcePeer expected to be the IPs used on the peerings?